# UIView in iphone sdk, how to update?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk

I found an older tutorial for the iphone sdk as it used the "Windows Based Application" template, and I used the "Cocoa Touch App" as a template.

The tutorial used UIViewController, I use UIView, so
I updated the code a bit, with my limited knowledge,

my code is almost working but one like keeps me from finishing it:

```
- (void)onTimer {
    [ball update];
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(ball.position.x - ball.radius, ball.position.y - ball.radius, ball.radius * 2.0, ball.radius * 2.0);
    [(BallView *)self.frame refresh:rect];
}
```

the line

```
[(BallView *)self.frame refresh:rect];
```

makes me trouble as it says: "cannot convert to a pointer type"

what do I need to tweak to display the simple ball in the tutorial?

regards,
mirza

Answer (score 0):

self.frame is a CGRect which is a data structure and not an object. That is why you cannot convert it to a pointer. (i think :P)